# Magento Admin Not Logging In (after domain transfer)

Tags: magento

Magento Admin page does not work when entering admin username and password. Cookies are not being stored. After transferring domains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re having problems logging in to the Magento admin (e.g. it redirects you back to the login page with no error) and there are many tutorials online on how to fix this issue. You go to the admin page enter your credentials and nothing happens, it just reloads the page. This typically happens after you transferred domains.

[Magento Admin http://www.expertmagentodevelopers.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/magento-admin-cant-login.png](http://www.expertmagentodevelopers.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/magento-admin-cant-login.png)

I will tell you the two steps that it took me to get it working.

**Step 1:** Login to phpMyAdmin or whatever you use to edit your database.
**Step 2:** Go to the core_config_data table
**Step 3:** Find general/locale/timezone and set the value to your local time zone so for me is America/Los_Angeles some people be America/New_York (if you have setup a magento installation before go copy those details) 
**Step 4:** Now find web/cookie/cookie_domain and set it to NULL (check the checkbox when editing it)
**Step 5:** Use FTP to clear var/cache and var/session

I hope that this will help individuals in need instead of them spending 4 hours searching the internet like I did to find the correct answer.

Comment: I had this issue after fixing the infamous "Invalid form key. Please refresh the page." Issue (had to update domain name in /<magento_html_dir>/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php). Anyway so then the URL was coming out wrong but fixed with reindex:
n98-magerun cache:clean, n98-magerun cache:flush, n98-magerun index:reindex:all

Answer (score 1):

if you have everything backed up, you can try the following :

- Rename app/etc/local.xml to app/etc/local.xml_old
- clear var/cache (and var/full_page_cache) and var/session (if you dont care about losing sessions)
- Re-install by following the installer (when hitting /yourwebsite/url.com) making sure to place the correct database name and authentication details

If you do this correctly it should resolve your issue, and re-connect the magento files to your database (essentially setting locale, as well as Base Urls) without affecting the stores commerce data.

Be warned, if there are badly written community or local extensions in your project, there is a risk that the installer can fail. If the project is "healthy", then there should be no issues. if it does fail, you could move your old local.xml file back to local.xml and you should be back in your predicament, where you started.

Again, make backups of everything important.