# magento Unable to login to admin - after domain change on new server

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

After I have moved my website to the new Domain and server  . I cant log into admin.

The admin Url Gets updated but I can't login . The front end home page appears but cant go to categories and products pages.

In the error logs it always show one table or the other missing like this time it shows

```
a:5:{i:0;s:101:"SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'xxxx_table.sales_flat_order' doesn't exist";i:1;s:3451:"#0 /var/www/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
```

Some how if I get over this table it shows another table missing next time .

I have done all the basic troubleshooting:

**changed core config URL.**

**Deleted cache and session and also core cache session path from core_config_data**

**Followed These:**

[Magento Admin Not Logging In (after domain transfer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16575737/magento-admin-not-logging-in-after-domain-transfer)
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/how_to_fix_login_for_admin_on_local_install#dokuwiki__top

No Luck after all this any Guesses, Tips or advice

Procedure of Backup:

Yes I have taken the backup of files and a entire database backup from PhpMyAdmin. Uploaded the file on the Root and then uploaded the database. Infact created the new database with same database name and username as previous  .Using same encryption key etc. One things I would like to mention I am modifying the host file to see this current development website  via Ip address because on the actual domain we have the live website ? Can this be a issue ?

Comment: Please let me know the exact process you followed while migrating your  website to new server and domain.

Did you take backup of your old DB as well as folder?

Comment: Yes I have taken the backup of files and a entire database backup from

Comment: Yes I have taken the backup of files and a entire database backup from PhpMyAdmin. Uploaded the file on the Root and then uploaded the database. Infact created the new database with same database name and username as previous .Using same encryption key etc.

Comment: It may be an issue of incorrect modification in host file.

But before checking that, you can follow these steps:

Truncate complete database and re-import from backup.

Go to core_config_data table and change values of path "web/secure/base_url" and "web/unsecure/base_url".

Check that whether there are correct DB credentials in app/etc/local.xml.

Remove session folder, cache folder and locks folder under /var folder.

Now try accessing your website again.

Comment: What is the error that shows when you try to enter with correct user name and password?? Does it shows invalid password or it doesnt shows any thing? Did you observe the URL? Does it changes or that too effects nothing? Did you try in different browsers?

Comment: It does not  show any errors. YES Url changes as if the username and password is correct and it wants to get redirected to dashboard.But it gives error page with error number .When I check the error logs it says--  Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'xxxx_table.sales_flat_order